# insertar array completo en mysql con reactjs y php

Tags: php, reactjs, react-hooks

tengo un formulario en reactjs donde hay una variable que se llama "nombre" y dos arrays dinamicos uno se llama "dato1" y el otro "dato2", cuando hago la petición POST desde reactjs me envia la información al php y lo guarda en base de datos hasta ahí bien, pero tengo un inconveniente si los arrays contienen mas información solo me guarda los dos primeros campos de dato1 y dato2 y el resto de campos del array no se guardan en base de datos.

**Necesito que se guarde el array dinámico completo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-browser-nvcee?file=/src/App.js

reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import {
  Grid,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircleOutline";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover
    }
  }
}))(TableRow);

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 1 },
  { value: 2, label: 2 },
  { value: 3, label: 3 }
];

function Pruebas() {
  const baseUrlAd =
    "https://www.inventarios.gemcont.com/apiGemcont/compras/ingresos/index2.php";
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [frameworkSeleccionado, setFrameworkSeleccionado] = useState({
    id_ingreso: "",
    nombre: "",
    dato1: "",
    dato2: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFrameworkSeleccionado((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
    console.log(frameworkSeleccionado);
  };

  
  const peticionPost = async () => {
    var f = new FormData();
    f.append("nombre", frameworkSeleccionado.nombre);
    /* Los datos están en la matriz bidimensional "roomInputs" */
    f.append("dato1", roomInputs[0].dato1);
    f.append("dato2", roomInputs[0].dato2);
    f.append("METHOD", "POST_prueba");
    await axios
      .post(baseUrlAd, f)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(data.concat(response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  

  const [roomInputs, setRoomInputs] = useState([{ dato1: "", dato2: "" }]);


  const handleRoomChange = (value, index, name) => {
    const list = [...roomInputs];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setRoomInputs(list);
  };

  const handleRemoveClickRoom = (index) => {
    const list = [...roomInputs];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setRoomInputs(list);
  };

  const handleAddClickRoom = () => {
    setRoomInputs([...roomInputs, { dato1: "", dato2: "" }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="content-wrapper">
      <div className="content-header">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Datos</h3>
              </div>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="nombre"
                        placeholder="nombre"
                        className="form-control"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <br />
                    <Grid item sm={12}>
                      <TableContainer component={Paper} variant="outlined">
                        <Table aria-label="customized table">
                          <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                              <TableCell>#</TableCell>
                              <TableCell align="left">dato1</TableCell>
                              <TableCell align="left">dato2</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          </TableHead>
                          <TableBody>
                            {roomInputs.map((x, i) => (
                              <StyledTableRow key={i}>
                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                  {i + 1}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">
                                  <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="dato1"
                                    value={options.value}
                                    //onChange={option => handleRoomChange(option, i, "dato1")}
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                      handleRoomChange(
                                        event.target.value,
                                        i,
                                        "dato1"
                                      )
                                    }
                                  />
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left">
                                  <input
                                    type="number"
                                    name="dato2"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    value={options.value}
                                    //onChange={option => handleRoomChange(option, i, "dato2")}
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                      handleRoomChange(
                                        event.target.value,
                                        i,
                                        "dato2"
                                      )
                                    }
                                  />
                                </TableCell>

                                <TableCell align="left">
                                  {roomInputs.length !== 1 && (
                                    <DeleteIcon
                                      onClick={() => handleRemoveClickRoom(i)}
                                      style={{
                                        marginRight: "10px",
                                        marginTop: "4px",
                                        cursor: "pointer"
                                      }}
                                    />
                                  )}
                                  {roomInputs.length - 1 === i && (
                                    <AddCircleOutlineIcon
                                      onClick={handleAddClickRoom}
                                      style={{
                                        marginTop: "4px",
                                        cursor: "pointer"
                                      }}
                                    />
                                  )}
                                </TableCell>
                              </StyledTableRow>
                            ))}
                          </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                      </TableContainer>
                    </Grid>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={() => peticionPost()}
                >
                  {" "}
                  Registrar
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pruebas;
```

php

```js
<?php

include '../../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


if($_POST['METHOD']=='POST_prueba'){
    unset($_POST['METHOD']);
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $dato1=$_POST['dato1'];
    $dato2=$_POST['dato2'];
    $query="insert into ingresos2(nombre,dato1,dato2) values ('$nombre','$dato1','$dato2')";
    $queryAutoIncrement="select MAX(id_ingreso) as id_ingreso from ingresos2";
    $resultado=metodoPost($query, $queryAutoIncrement);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}


header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

mysql

tengo una sola tabla que se llama "ingresos2" y tiene 4 campos: id_ingreso, nombre, dato1 y dato2

Comment: ¿Y el código de la función `metodoPost()`? ¿Y dónde están las modificaciones que sugerí en mi respuesta anterior? Estás enviando un único valor en vez de varios.

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando tus inputs dinamicamante pero no estas obteniendo los datos dinamicamente, debes obtener todos los datos ingresados, al especificar la posicion estas consultando de manera estatica, lo que debes hacer es obtener todo el array y enviarlo,ya en tu php lo recorres e insertas cada posicion

No hagas esto

```
f.append("dato1", roomInputs[0].dato1);
```

Has esto

```
f.append("data", JSON.stringify(roomInputs));
```

Suponiendo que por cada linea de input debes gererar un registro en base de datos(*Auque estas repitiendo el nombre por cada regsitro*)

```
 if($_POST['METHOD']=='POST_prueba'){
        unset($_POST['METHOD']);
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
         $data=json_decode($_POST['data']);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $dato1=$row['dato1'];
    $dato2=$row['dato2'];
  //aqui debes hacer cada inserción en base de datos
}
        $query="insert into ingresos2(nombre,dato1,dato2) values ('$nombre','$dato1','$dato2')";
        $queryAutoIncrement="select MAX(id_ingreso) as id_ingreso from ingresos2";
        $resultado=metodoPost($query, $queryAutoIncrement);
        echo json_encode($resultado);
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: cambie el codigo php que enviaste y cambie en reactjs f.append("dato1", roomInputs[0].dato1); y reactjs f.append("dato2", roomInputs[0].dato2);  por  f.append("data", JSON.stringify(roomInputs)); pero no me guarda en base de datos

Comment: muestra los datos que llegan php, ya en react no tienes nada mas que hacer, ya debes tratar tus datos en php

Comment: he intentado solucionar la parte en php con el codigo que subio pero no he logrado que guarde.

Comment: pues muestra que tienes, te doy la lógica pero no puedo hacerte el código

Comment: @CristianCamilo, como te he dicho en incontables ocasiones, si no proporcionas la implementación de la función `metodoPost()` no podremos ayudarte. Quizá esa función sea completamente innecesaria o no tenga la gestión de errores adecuada.